# Viber does not work (white windows) on Ubuntu 18.04 after last update

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, viber

After last update Viber does not work on Ubuntu 18.04. The notification icon is working, but the Viber windows is blank (white).

[image: Viber white windows]

Removing and reinstalling Viber did not help. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SolusProject/comments/9d4a5q/viber_white_screen_after_latest_update/) , but is was a lot of time to do, so I decided to share the solution here, so help everybody, who has the same problem.

The working solution: remove `~/.cache/qtshadercache` directory, and restart Viber.